# Why does my Excel VBA code not save an open Word document?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a module that I am using to loop through several folders, find Word documents with a certain name, accept all changes and remove comments. However, my code is failing when I use the .SaveAs2 method to save the Word file as the name of the Word file + '_FINAL'. I get a "run-time error 4605 application-defined or object-defined error" message and it doesn't run. Here's my code below:

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim sPath As String     ' Contains folder path of where this file is located
    Dim FileSystem As Object

    ' Set folder path to where this file is located
    sPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    BrowseFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(sPath)
End Sub

Public Sub BrowseFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder

    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        BrowseFolder SubFolder
    Next

    Dim File

    For Each File In Folder.Files
        If InStr(File, "Narrative_updated.doc") <> 0 Then
            ' Pass onto Word sub
             FinalizeWord (File)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub FinalizeWord(File)
    Dim appWord As Word.Application
    Dim sFileName As String

    Set appWord = New Word.Application

    appWord.Visible = True
    appWord.Documents.Open fileName:=File
    appWord.DisplayAlerts = False
    appWord.Activate

    ' Set fileName to contain document name, will be used to save as final
    sFileName = appWord.ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & Left(appWord.ActiveDocument.Name, InStrRev(appWord.ActiveDocument.Name, ".") - 1) & "_FINAL.docx"

    ' Set default view to print layout view in case that the document is protected
    appWord.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintView

    ' Accept all track changes
    appWord.ActiveDocument.Revisions.AcceptAll

    ' Remove all comments
    appWord.ActiveDocument.DeleteAllComments

    ' Save As filename_FINAL.docx
    appWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 sFileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any solutions that can help?

Comment: I believe `wdFormatXMLDocument` corresponds to the `.xml` extension, so you wouldn't want `.doc` in the filename?

Comment: @BigBen I tried removing .doc from the filename. Same error shows up.

Comment: try changing `.doc` to `.xml`?

Comment: I changed ```wdFormatXMLDocument``` to ```wdFormatDocumentDefault``` and still getting the same issue.

Comment: Did you add `.docx` then to the filename?

Comment: @BigBen no luck. I updated the code on the original post to show what it looks like now.

Comment: `wdFormatDocumentDefault` will look at what is set in the Word configuration, which may not be the same on every machine and may not match the file extension used. Choose the member of the Enum that matches the file extension. Also, if you use one named argument then all the arguments need to be named. In `SaveAs2` you need an argument name before `sFileName`. After you make those corrections, what happens?